# How to get String Resource within ViewPager Adapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-resources

I trying to set the title for my viewpager, I can't seem to get it to work. I tried Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.title1); and also tried to pass a context. Could anyone help me?

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.create(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.title1);

        case 1:
            return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.title1);

        case 2:
            return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.title1);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-02 17:40:33.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 17:40:33.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3116): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050003
09-02 17:40:33.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3116):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
09-02 17:40:33.160: E/AndroidRuntime(3116):     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:314)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, according to your error message **you do not have a String with the ID** you are requesting.

> Could it be that you are supporting **multi languages** and only have this
>   kind of String-ID for a specific language?

Anyways, this line of code:

```
String yourstring = getResources().getString(R.string.yourstring);
```

is how to get a String from Resources. `getResources()` can be called whenever you are in a class extending `Context`, such as `Activity`.

Comment: cannot access getResources()

Answer (score 46):

you should call getString from an activity's context, change your code to

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context nContext) {
        super(fm);
        context = nContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.create(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            return context.getString(R.string.title1);

        case 1:
            return context.getString(R.string.title1);

        case 2:
            return context.getString(R.string.title1);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to access string resources from outside of an activity, then you need to pass the context in to that class (which you stated you have already done), and then call

```
String str = context.getResources().getString(R.string.some_string);
```

Also check your `strings.xml` file to make sure that you are using the string id correctly. 
If you're using android studio you should be able to simply start typing `R.string.` and it will then show suggestions from the strings.xml file. If you do not see your resource here, then that may indicate a problem with the way you are storing your resources, as opposed to how you are trying to access them.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch `String` inside your `Resources` without gaining `Resources`. So try to pull your `Resources` with `getResources()` with your `Context`.

If your are inside `Activity` or `Service` then context is there. If outside then try to pull `Context` first  with `getApplicationContext()` and on that pull the resources and pull your `String` in the end on it.

As per your Code these snippet would't  throw any exception if `resources` and mentioned `String` id's are pulled properly.

```
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
  {
    switch (position) 
    {
    case 0:
           return getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
    case 1:
           return getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
    case 2:
           return getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
     }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the available using: `getContext().getString(resId)` like:

```
getContext().getString(R.string.title1)
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.String.title1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the view pager won't show each text to the assigned screen consistently. I needed to create separate layout for each page and assign the text from within the layout, so when flipping the pages each page will show a layout with its text.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not allowed to call getResources() in your viewPager Adapter, you need to declare it as a static variable in the parent activity

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin I do this by sending context to the adapter, as below:

```
class FmAdapter(val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    private val fragments = arrayListOf<Fragments>()

    init {
        fragments.add(Fragments(R.string.title1, FragmentOne()))
        fragments.add(Fragments(R.string.title2, FragmentTwo()))
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int = fragments.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = fragments[position].fragment

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? = context.getString(fragments[position].title)
}
```

with data class:

```
data class Fragments(@StringRes val title: Int, val fragment: Fragment)
```

and simple call from activity, like:

```
rv.adapter = FmAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
```